# How to write generic tearDown methd for junit?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, ehcache

In my project( spring boot application) I have around 200+ test cases. Recently we have implemented one factory bean for cache manager (ehcache) which is in my startup class(@SpringBootApplication).

My problem is that , once that startup class with that factory bean is getting executed by one test cases ,  all the subsequent testcase are getting failed with error...

"Another CacheManager with same name 'appCacheManager' already exists in the same VM."

To resolve this I have added teardown method with body like this …

```
public void tearDown() {
    MyCustomCacheManager customCacheManager = (MyCustomCacheManager) context.getBean("yourCustomCacheManagerBean");

    try {
        net.sf.ehcache.Cache cache = customCacheManager.getCache();
        net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager cacheManager = cache.getCacheManager();
        cacheManager.removeCache("nameOfYourCache");
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    context.destroy();
    context = null;
}
```

By my problem is that in this I have add this teardown method in all existing testcases.

Can we have something which can be implemented , so that teardown method will called up automatically after each test cases , I do not have to add teardown in each and every JUNIT classes...

May be some generic teardown with some annotation in existing test cases...

Please advice.....

Comment: Are you using JUnit 4 or 5?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking on two approaches to perform that:

1. Create a base class that every unit test will need to extend and implement the tearDown() method there.
2. Use AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) in order to execute the tearDown() method functionality after every method on your test package.

Comment: You don't usually run tests in containers that enable aop.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is implementing this behavior using `TestExecutionListener` and you can too.

Simply create the `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` file with following content:

```
org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener=\
com.yourpackage.CacheTestExecutionListener
```

...and implement the listener:

```java
public class CacheTestExecutionListener implements TestExecutionListener {
    @Override
    public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        // testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(...)
    }
}
```

And that should be it - no need to do any changes in existing tests.

Answer (score 0):

It does look like you're Usain JUnit 4, but if you're using 5, you can [write an extension](https://blog.codefx.org/design/architecture/junit-5-extension-model/) that would allow you to annotate test classes with it to inject the behavior.